# How to detect when the RPSystemBroadcastPickerView is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit, rpsystembroadcastpickerview

I am using `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` to start a system-wide screen recording from my app. The `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` is completely autonomous in starting the recording and everything, which I guess makes sense - only user can start the screen recording by explicitly tapping the button.

I need to know when the `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` is tapped. Right now the UI is showing keyboard, which I want to keep showing (it is a chat app). However, the form showing the list of broadcast extensions to pick one is being shown under the keyboard. See following image:

[image]

This effectively prevents the user to start the broadcast. If I knew when the user tapped `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView`, I could manually hide the keyboard at that moment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find any callbacks for that, but you can create your transparent button, add it above the **RPSystemBroadcastPickerView**. When user will tap on your button you will be able to hide the keyboard and than transfer the action to the **RPSystemBroadcastPickerView** using the code:

```
for subview in screenSharingProviderPickerView.subviews {
    if let button = subview as? UIButton {
         button.sendActions(for: UIControlEvents.allTouchEvents)
    }
}
```

Comment: really ugly workaround, but it works.. I guess it works for now.. thanks!

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Hi, I m doing the same RPSystemBroadcastPickerView in button action . But, My recorded video is automatically saving in Camera roll. How to detect screen record completed from our app and how to show that recorded video in our app ? Is there any method for handle this? Can guide me. ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485367/screen-recording-when-my-ios-app-is-in-background-with-replaykit Can u help me on this ??

Answer (score 2):

I found similar solution to accepted answer, but you don't need to create transparent button.
I just add additional target-action pair to the picker button dispatch table, with `#selector` which will be fired, when button is pressed.

```
// picker is an instance of RPSystemBroadcastPickerView
for subview in picker.subviews {
    if let button = subview as? UIButton {
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}

// You can also accept _ sender: UIButton as parameter, if you need to.
@objc func pickerAction() {
    // called when user press on RPSystemBroadcastPickerView
}
```

> Note: Keep in mind that, if Apple change hierarchy of this view in the future, you probably need to update application as well.