# Is there a way to finish broadcast gracefully from within RPBroadcastSampleHandler?

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, replaykit, rpbroadcastsamplehandler

I am implementing a broadcast upload extension in iOS using my own custom `SampleHandler` extending `RPBroadcastSampleHandler`. The problem is pretty easy - I need a way to gracefully end the broadcast from within the extension.

The requirement is to stop broadcasting and turn off screen recording when all the other users stop watching the broadcast. I can easily detect that case. However, it seems that `RPBroadcastSampleHandler` does not provide a way to finish it, at least not a graceful way.

Based on [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler), there is a [`broadcastFinished()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler/2143169-broadcastfinished) callback on broadcast finishing (when the user ends it), and there is a way to finish it when there is an error - [`finishBroadcastWithError(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpbroadcastsamplehandler/2721526-finishbroadcastwitherror). I could provide some nice error message and end it with an error, but I would prefer to just end it without showing any error at all - I don't want to indicate that there was any error, since this is intended behavior.

Anyone have a way on how to achieve this?

Comment: did you got any solution for same?

Comment: @iOSLifee as far as I know, there is no way to do this.. but if you come up with any good solution, please, let me know

Comment: ok sure will let you know

Comment: Have you got any solution on it.. because i am facing same issue and not able to dismiss to gracefully

Comment: @YogeshDalavi we just disconnect from the broadcast and in our app we try to open `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` that allows the user to turn it off.. We haven't found a way to turn it off gracefully (the user has to do it AFAIK)

Comment: Yes i have tried that way using RPSystemBroadcastPickerView . User can tap on top red bar to stop  screen share. But not found a way to do it programatically without user interaction.

Comment: @YogeshDalavi https://stackoverflow.com/q/51982235/2912282

Answer (score 3):

You should do it using Obj-C code. As you can see on the [Telegram Official repository](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/Telegram-iOS/blob/master/Telegram/BroadcastUpload/BroadcastUploadExtension.swift) they use BroadcastUploadHelpers in order to stop the sampleHandler gracefully.

```
void finishBroadcastGracefully(RPBroadcastSampleHandler * _Nonnull broadcastSampleHandler) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnonnull"
[broadcastSampleHandler finishBroadcastWithError:nil];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```